# How to set 'local storage for attribute in jquery'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, local-storage

I'm developing my own site and it supports multi themes for example (light & dark) theme when you click on option it apply theme and no problem to face but when you reload page you have then to choose theme again.

I've tried to fix that by adding key and value for local storage and I saw a lot of tutorials about it and no progress.

> **HTML Code**

- ***Head***

  - `<link rel=stylesheet" href="view/light-view.css">`
    *default theme it will changes after user choose theme and replace **light-view.css** with theme name.*
- ***Body***

  - `<span class="mode-toggler" data-value="view/light-view.css">Light</span>`
  - `<span class="mode-toggler" data-value="view/dark-view.css">Dark</span>`
    *set data-value into css default theme after click I achieve this by jquery*

> **jQuery Code**

```
$('.mode-toggler').click(function() {

    // Change attribute of css default theme by checking for statements with href attribute contains view keyword
    $("link[href*='view']").attr("href", $(this).attr("data-value");

});
```

Comment: Not directly related, but this might also be of interest to you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: Using that media query, you can change the theme of your site based on what the user has selected to be the system-wide theme.

Comment: Thanks sir, I succeeded at applying theme but the problem I'm facing is add it to web storage

Comment: Well, you could just do 
`window.localStorage.setItem("theme", $(this).attr("data-value"))`, right?

Comment: @grooveplex nothing happend but when I get theme item from console localStorage.theme it gives me "view/dark-view.css" this means it changed

Comment: well, then you have to implement the logic to change the theme :-)

Comment: @grooveplex I will try thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So firstly you need to set in localstorage, the user selected theme:

```
$('.mode-toggler').click(function() {

    // Change attribute of css default theme by checking for statements with href attribute contains view keyword
    $("link[href*='view']").attr("href", $(this).attr("data-value"));

    // set localstorage
    localstorage.setItem("selectedTheme",  $(this).attr("data-value"));

});
```

And when you load the webpage next time, you will have to check for selectedTheme even before your page has loaded. **Just include this script in you head tag.**

```
<script>
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = localstorage.getItem("selectedTheme") || "view/light-view.css";
document.head.appendChild(link);
</script>
```

But I am afraid that this might lead to a flicker because at first, the raw html(without CSS) will get painted in your browser and then the whole of CSS gets inserted and DOM repaints with CSS. You can solve this by removing theme related CSS in a separate file(say darktheme.css) and put all other CSS in a constant css file(styles.css). While the page loads, load it with `styles.css` and load the `*theme.css` through script tag.

Comment: `You can solve this by removing theme related CSS in a separate file(say darktheme.css) and put all other CSS in a constant css file(styles.css).` or include a class like `.theme-dark` at body level and just toggle the classes?

Comment: Colours and Backgrounds are separated in light & dark view because it's very big for classes, can I ask you if possible to add the localStorage.getItem("selectedTheme") to original theme link without creating a new element?

Comment: OMG... I can't believe I missed this. :|  Life will be lot more simple if you add a script at the end of `body` to detect the selected theme and toggle a class at body....

Comment: Thanks sir it works this will help me very much in my coming projects the problem was the script must placed at bottom, I will try to place localStorage into my original link.